# Given a set of integers and operators, find if number is obtainable

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, formal-languages

Let's say I have a set of sequential integers $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots,x_n)$ and operators $(+,-,\times,/,(,))$ (arithmetic operators and parenthesis).

Now say we can have any $t$ numbers from the set (repetition allowed), then, given a number
 $n \leq xn^3$ (since that's the max possible in our case), is there a straight-forward method of finding if $n$ is obtainable from our set of numbers and operators?

For example, if our set is $(1,2,3,4)$ and we can use $t=3$ numbers, then the max is $4\times4\times4 = 64$.
now given a number, say $21$, we want to apply an algorithm to find out if that number is obtainable (in this case, $(3+4)\times3$), or not (like $22$).

Seems to me like one has to de-compose the number using the available set somehow, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: @ml0105: Could you give more details of the reduction you have in mind? For example, which $(t,(x_i),n)$ instance would correspond to satisfiability of $(A\lor B)\land(A\lor \neg B)$?

Comment: Are you intentionally reusing $n$?

Comment: I'm guessing $xn^3$ should be $x_n^3$? You should really not use $n$ for the number in the left hand side of that inequality, as it is not the same $n$ as in the right hand side!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are given a subset of $\mathbb Z$ and a bunch of functions $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\mapsto\mathbb Z_2$ and you want to know if given an integer $m$ we can get to $n$ by taking two numbers from the set, applying one of the functions, then taking a number from from the set and applying the function to that number and so on....

The answer is that it is not possible, for example take one function: $f(x,y)=3x+1$ if $x$ is odd and $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ if $x$ is even.and let the set have only one number. We can't know if we can get to $1$ or not easily.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be about arbitrary functions but binary operators (ignoring parentheses which are not really operators).  Simply excluding unary operators is enough to remove the unboundedness problem you describe.

Comment: We can turn it into a binary function easily.

Comment: But each use of that binary function will reduce the number of variables by $1$.  Since $t$ is a parameter, this will not result in unbounded (or difficult to bound) behaviour as in the Collatz problem.